# Laravel Order by Pivot Table Timestamp, Many to Many Relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, sql-order-by

I am currently ordering by the timestamp of a model (the Url model) but I want to order by the timestamp of the pivot table instead. Tried a few things but no dice. Can someone help see where I'm going wrong with this?

This is what I have so far.

```
class Url extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    // ... etc ...
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
    public function hostname()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Hostname::class);
    }   
}

class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;
    // ... etc ...
    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }
    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }
    public function urls()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Url::class)
            ->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

This is a snippet from the Repository.

```
public function paginate() 
 { 
 return Url::query()
 ->with(['users'=>function($query)
 {
 $query
 ->select('id', 'username', 'slug')
 ->where([
 'active'=>true
 ]);
 }])
 ->with(['hostname'=>function($query)
 {
 $query
 ->select('id', 'hostname', 'slug')
 ->where([
 'active'=>true
 ]);
 }])
 ->select('id', 'url', 'title', 'hostname_id', 'updated_at')
 ->where([
 'active'=>true
 ])
 ->orderByDesc('created_at') // <-- replace this
 ->paginate();
 }
```

Any thoughts on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need [JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html):

```
public function paginate() 
{ 
    return Url::query()
        ->with(['users' => function($query) {
            $query->select('id', 'username', 'slug')
                  ->where(['active' => true]);
        }])
        ->with(['hostname' => function($query) {
            $query->select('id', 'hostname', 'slug')
                  ->where(['active' => true]);
        }])
        ->join('url_user', 'urls.id', '=', 'url_user.url_id') // join with the pivot table
        ->select('urls.id', 'urls.url', 'urls.title', 'urls.hostname_id', 'urls.updated_at')
        ->where(['urls.active' => true])
        ->orderByDesc('url_user.created_at')
        ->paginate();
}
```